# Configuring listener_endpoint in httr when using Rstudio server

Tags: r, google-analytics, rstudio, httr, rstudio-server

I;'m struggling to connect to Google Analytics with `httr` oauth2.0 function

```
oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("google")
  , oauth_app("google", client.id, client.secret)
  , scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly")
```

It works perfectly in my local Rstudio, but it breaks in AWS-based Rstudio Server. The error appears when I agree to pass data in browser and Google redirects me to the page
http://localhost:1410/?state=codehere

When launching authentication in local Rstudio, browser responds with a message - *Authentication complete. Please close this page and return to R*, incase of Rstudio server it's just *This webpage is not available*

I suspect I need to change *listener_endpoint* configuration, but how? Should I put my Rstudio server address instead of default 127.0.0.1? Or is it flaw of *httr+Rtudio server* and I should not bother?

Comment: do it locally. save the token as an r data file. upload that to AWS and just used the cached token.

Comment: That's exactly what I do now, but I think other people would be interested in more elegant solution too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect URI is part of the problem. Httr's oauth2.0_token() function identify the correct one. When you set up your project, Google Analytics created two redirect URIs, one that can be used on your RStudio IDE (local) and one that can be used in the RStudio web-based environment for out-of-of band authentication: "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"

Once you've authenticated, the following code should work.

```
library(httr)
ga_id         <- YourProjectID
client_id     <- YourClientID
redirect_uri  <- 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
scope         <- YourScope 
client_secret <- YourSecret
response_type <-'code'

auth1 <- oauth2.0_token(
   endpoint = oauth_endpoints("google"),
   app = oauth_app(
      "google", 
      key = client_id, 
      secret = client_secret
      ),
   scope,
   use_oob = TRUE,
   cache = TRUE
)
```

-- Ann

Answer (score 0):

You could use out-of-band authentication -

```
options(httr_oob_default = TRUE)
```